# How to start my instance again after trial expiring today, upgrading, enabling billing, adding money?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The error I get is that of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/884107) and not of [this other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/852548).  The OP in first question, however, says he solved his problem by paying for the service.  I also thought payment was the problem with me, but upgrading the account, enabling billing and adding money to the account (I added $50 today and my instance is a g1-small) did not allow me start the instance.  I can't create a snapshot of it either.  I can't create another instance in the project either. I **can** however create another project and run an instance in another project.  (No problem there.)

```
C:\gcloud>gcloud compute instances start screenshot-1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.start) HTTPError 400: The resource 'projects/screenshot-203117/zones/us-east1-b/disks/screenshot-1' is not ready
```

The trial expired today and I noticed they had shutdown the instance.  It's been a few hours already after paying for the service and no change in the scenario.  How can I start this instance and have everything back to normal?

**IMPORTANT ADDENDUM**: I just noticed the VM instance I can't start has a disk being restored from a snapshot.  Why did that happen?  See the message in this image link below.

[a disk is being restored from a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THkhH.png)

```
C:\gcloud>gcloud compute disks list
NAME          ZONE        SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
screenshot-1  us-east1-b  10       pd-standard  RESTORING
```

Comment: It seems like you been affected with some  transient issue after [upgrading your GCP account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) to a paid account. Please open a [private issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901) with Google cloud platform issue-tracker. While opening the report, please mention a detailed issue description along with your project number.